# Float formatting and output to ascii file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, format

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this::

```
>>> df
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
          0         1         2         3   
0  0.445598  0.173835  0.343415  0.682252  
1  0.881592  0.696942  0.702232  0.696724  
2  0.662527  0.955193  0.131016  0.609548
```

and I'd simply like an ascii output such as:

```
       0      1      2      3 
0  0.446  0.174  0.343  0.682 
1  0.882  0.697  0.702  0.697 
2  0.663  0.955  0.131  0.610
```

I can use

```
df = df.round(3)
```

but then

```
data.to_ascii
```

screws up the formatting.

Comment: Can you show the code that screws up something?

Comment: what is the result of `df = df.round(3)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_string()`.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df.round(3).to_string())

#Output
       0      1      2      3
0  0.446  0.174  0.343  0.682
1  0.882  0.697  0.702  0.697
2  0.663  0.955  0.131  0.610
```